# javafx sound/video playback

Tags: java, video, javafx, mp3, playback

I've been trying playback some mp3, videos using JavaFX without a result. I have also searched through every topic on this forum looking for solution without success... 
If anyone can help me I would appreciate

**Here's my code:**

```
  @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Embedded Media Player");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 540, 241);
    File f = new File("src/sample/test2.mp3");

    Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

    MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

    System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getMedia() = " + mediaPlayer.getMedia().getSource());
    System.out.println("mp.getStatus() = " + mediaPlayer.getStatus());
    System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration() = " + mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration());
    System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getMedia().getSource() = " + mediaPlayer.getMedia().getSource());

    ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    mediaPlayer.play();
```

**and the output:**

```
mediaPlayer.getMedia() = file:/C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/okon/src/sample/test2.mp3
mp.getStatus() = UNKNOWN
mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration() = UNKNOWN
mediaPlayer.getMedia().getSource() = file:/C:/Users/Piotr/Desktop/okon/src/sample/test2.mp3
```

**Edit:**
Moving to Ubuntu solved my problems

Comment: Your location seems to be alright. can you try using `Media media = new Media(getClass().getResource("/sample/test2.mp3").toExternalForm());` and update your finding?

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener :

mediaPlayer.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                System.out.println("mp.getStatus() = " + mediaPlayer.getStatus());
                System.out.println("mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration() = " + mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration());
            }
        });